# Optional and Java Spring Testing

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have a problem with my ControllerTest. I'm not sure how to test for the Optional - does someone know how? The other test gives me a NullPointerException for the stubbing : `when(couponService.getCouponById(id)).thenReturn(expectedCoupon);`
Would be awesome if someone could help me.

```java
public class CouponControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private CouponService couponService;
    
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Test
    public void checkAndUpdateCoupon() throws Exception {
        int id = 1;
        int userId = 1;
        
        Coupon expectedCoupon = new Coupon(1, 1);
        when(couponService.getCouponById(id)).thenReturn(expectedCoupon);
        
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        when(userService.getAllUser()).thenReturn(userList);
        
        List<Coupon> couponList = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
        when(couponService.getAllCoupons()).thenReturn(couponList);
        
        mockMvc.perform(get("/checkCoupon")
                .param("id", "1")
                .param("userId", "1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("couponPage"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("error", "Not correct user id or coupon id."))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("users", userList))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("coupons", couponList));
                
        
        verify(couponService).updateCoupons(id, userId);
    }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class CouponController {

    @Autowired
    CouponService couponService;
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/checkCoupon")
    public String checkCoupon(ModelMap model, @RequestParam Integer id, @RequestParam Integer userId, Coupon coupon) {
        Optional<Coupon> couponFromDatabase = couponService.byUserIdAndId(coupon.getUserId(), coupon.getId());
        if(couponFromDatabase.isEmpty()) {
            String error = "Not correct user id or coupon id.";
            model.addAttribute("error", error);
        } else {
            String message = couponService.updateCoupons(id, userId);
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
        }
        
        List<User> userList = userService.getAllUser();
        model.addAttribute("users", userList);
        List<Coupon> couponList = couponService.getAllCoupons();
        model.addAttribute("coupons", couponList);
        return "couponPage";
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. You think there's a problem in the test or in the production code?

Comment: Your test isn't annotated with anything, so why and how should Spring inject dependencies into it or even mock them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do some changes in mocking the first service.

```
when( couponService.byUserIdAndId(anyLong(), anyLong()) ).thenReturn( Optional.of(expectedCoupon) );
```

Here the `anyLong()` refer to any Incoming long data type number.

Override your existing code with this above line.

Comment: Also see [comment by M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131726/optional-and-java-spring-testing#comment115148623_65131726)